# Z transform of $\sum_{k=0}^{n}3^{k}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, closed-form, z-transform

My task is to calculate z transform of signal $x[n]=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}3^{k}$ ?

By definition, $$ \begin{align}
X(z) &= \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty}x[n]z^{-n} \\
 &= \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}3^{k}\right)z^{-n} \\
 &= \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty}(3^{0}+3^{1}+3^{2}+...+3^{n})z^{-n} \\
\end{align}$$

but I don't know how to deal with this sum. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. Observe that, using
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}a^{k}=\frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}, \quad a \neq 1,
$$ you get
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}3^{k}=\frac{3^{n+1}-1}2
$$ then
$$
X(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(3^{0}+3^{1}+3^{2}+...+3^{n})z^{-n}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{3^{n+1}-1}2\right)z^{-n}
$$ which you may simplify.

Comment: Got it now! Thanks a lot!